# exceptions in other procedure without exiting the procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a materialized view of the REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND type, I have a stored procedure to refresh several materialized views. How can I make an exception that records in an error log table, but does not stop the procedure, that records the error line, but continue with the refresh of the following materialized view 2. The materialized views generate a lot of problems, like handling a table of loading errors?

Thank you.

```
create or replace procedure actualizar_vistaM 
is 
begin
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('VIEW 1')

DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('VIEW 2')

exception
when others then
INSERT INTO errors VALUES (value1,value2,value3)

end;
```

Comment: Hint: Save Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd have to enclose each refresh into its own begin-exception-end block.

```
create or replace procedure actualizar_vistaM 
is 
begin
  begin
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('VIEW 1');
  exception
    when others then
      insert into errors values (...);
  end;
  
  --
  
  begin
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('VIEW 2');
  exception
    when others then
      insert into errors values (...);
  end;
end;
```